# Weird Behavior in System.Console.Write()

Tags: c#

Doing this as a test:

```
string text1 = "Letter";
string text2 = "Number";

System.Console.Write("{0}" + " {0}" + " {0}", text1, " {0}", text2);
```

results in this output:

```
Letter Letter Letter
```

Shouldn't this be the output?

```
Letter Letter Letter Number
```

Doing this:

```
System.Console.Write("{0}" + " {0}" + " {0}", text1, " {1}", text2);
```

Also results in this output:

```
Letter Letter Letter
```

Comment: You need to use `{1}` to reference the 2nd parameter

Comment: tested it same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No the output is correct, only the first text value provided to the this Console.Write() method overload is the format that may contain the placeholders.

The actual format you're using is `"{0}" + " {0}" + " {0}"` in your case (which effectively evaluates to `"{0} {0} {0}"`). The rest of your call is now provided as individual arguments:

- `text1` as first argument, used to replace all occurrences of `{0}`
- `" {0}"` as second argument, used to replace all occurrances of `{1}`
- `text2` as third argument, used to replace all occurrances of `{2}`

And since the actual format text only contains the placeholder `{0}` you'll never see the other provided arguments in the resulting text.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the right output:

```
System.Console.Write("{0} {0} {0} {1}", text1, text2);
```

There are several things wrong with your understanding of the function and string formatting.

1. The first parameter to Write() is the string you want to output
2. the parameters after the 1st parameter will NOT be concatenated to string in the first parameter unless referenced using `{0}, {1}, etc..`
3. There will be no compiler error since this is a valid call to the method. The `" 0"` and `text2` parameters are ignored by the compiler since they are not referenced in the original string.

Comment: Or even better, stylisticly: `Console.Write( "{0} {0} {0} {1}", text1, text2 );`

Comment: Thanks @stackErr i know that but i am asking what is the behavior in the other example i gave? Why doesn't it work and why doesn't it throw no errors either?

Comment: The following should help to explain 'Composite Formatting'.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GeorgeOscStephan added some explanation. You should read the docs as suggested by Stringfellow on strings and composite formatting

Comment: But even if i do this  `System.Console.Write("{0}" + " {0}" + " {0}", text1, " {1}", text2);` It still produces the same result. It just ignores anything after the first argument even tho i have given other arguments too. I need to change the way i give the argument to make it work but i don't understand hwy it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation as to why your code isn't working:

First, lets break down your line:

```
System.Console.Write("{0}" + " {0}" + " {0}", text1, " {0}", text2);
```

This line will simplify to this:

```
System.Console.Write("{0} {0} {0}", text1, " {0}", text2);
```

Keep in mind that the first parameter is the string to output. In this case `"{0} {0} {0}"`. Any parameters after that string are parameters to replace in your original string, such as `{0}` or `{1}`, etc. These parameters are used as they are needed.

`System.Console.Write`, in the context you're using it expects a string and it searches for parameters, such as `{0}` and `{1}`, etc. Because you are using only one parameter, `{0}`, it is only grabbing the first parameter after the string, which is `text1`. Any more parameters after that are simply ignored, or more specifically, they are unused. So the compiler is basically simplifying your line to this:

```
System.Console.Write("{0}" + " {0}" + " {0}", text1);
```

Comment: Just nitpicking but OP is passing a string and 3 other parameters: `text1`, `" {0}"`, and `text2`

Comment: @stackErr - Yes, but because he's only referencing one, `{0}`, then the compiler is ignoring the other parameters. More specifically, its not ignoring the parameters, but simply not using them.